# No output of Perl script called from Java

Tags: java, shell, perl, ssh

I am using Ganymed ssh lib in Java to connect to Linux machine and execute some unix scripts, and display their output.

I am running a parent shell script which in turn runs few other sub-scripts and finally a perl script. All work well for the shell scripts, but when it reaches the perl script, I stop getting any output.

**If I run the parent script manually on Linux server I see output from perl without issues**.

Here's the relevant java code, connecting to the machine and calling the shell script, and returning a BufferedReader from where the output could be read line by line :

```
try {
            conn = new Connection(server);
            conn.connect();
            boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPublicKey(user, keyfile, keyfilePass);
            if (isAuthenticated == false) {
                throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");
            }
            sess = conn.openSession();
            if (param == null) {
                sess.execCommand(". ./.bash_profile; cd $APP_HOME; ./parent_script.sh");
            }
            else {...}

            InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My parent shell script called looks like this :

```
./start1  #script1 output OK
./start2  #script2 output OK
./start3  #script3 output OK
/u01/app/perl_script.pl # NO OUTPUT HERE :(
```

Would anyone have any idea why this happens ?

**EDIT : Adding perl script**

```
#!/u01/app/repo/code/sh/perl.sh
use FindBin qw/ $Bin /;
use File::Basename qw/ dirname /;
use lib (dirname($Bin). "/pm" );
use Capture::Tiny qw/:all/;
use Data::Dumper;
use Archive::Zip;
use XML::Simple;
use MXA;
my $mx = new MXA;
chdir $mx->config->{$APP_HOME};
warn Dumper { targets => $mx->config->{RTBS} };
foreach my $target (keys %{ $mx->config->{RTBS}->{Targets} }) {
        my $cfg = $mx->config->{RTBS}->{Targets}->{$target};
        my @commands = (
                                        [
                                        ...
                                        ],
                                        [
                                        'unzip',
                                        '-o',
                                        "$cfg->{ConfigName}.zip",
                                        'Internal/AdapterConfig/Driver.xml'
                                        ],
                    [
                    'zip',
                    "$cfg->{ConfigName}.zip",
                    'Internal/AdapterConfig/Driver.xml'
                    ],
                    [
                    'rm -rf Internal'
                    ],
                    [
                    "rm -f $cfg->{ConfigName}.zip"
                    ],
                                );
        foreach my $cmnd (@commands) {
                warn Dumper { command => $cmnd };
                my ($stdout, $stderr, $status) = capture {
                        system(@{ $cmnd });
                };
                warn Dumper { stdout => $stdout,
                                                stderr => $stderr,
                                                status => $status };
        }
=pod
        warn "runnnig -scriptant /ANT_FILE:mxrt.RT_${target}argets_std.xml /ANT_TARGET:exportConfig -jopt:-DconfigName=Fixing -jopt:-DfileName=Fixing.zip');
        ($stdout, $stderr, $status) = capture {
                system('./command.app', '-scriptant -parameters');
        }
        ($stdout, $stderr, $status) = capture {
                system('unzip Real-time.zip Internal/AdapterConfig/Driver.xml');
        };
        my $xml = XMLin('Internal/AdapterConfig/MDPDriver.xml');
        print Dumper { xml => $xml };
   [[ ${AREAS} == "pr" ]] && {
      ${PREFIX}/substitute_mdp_driver_parts Internal/AdapterConfig/Driver.xml 123 controller@mdp-a-n1,controller@mdp-a-n2
   } || {
      ${PREFIX}/substitute_mdp_driver_parts Internal/AdapterConfig/Driver.xml z8pnOYpulGnWrR47y5UH0e96IU0OLadFdW/Bm controller@md-uat-n1,controller@md-uat-n2
   }
   zip Real-time.zip Internal/AdapterConfig/Driver.xml
   rm -rf Internal
   rm -f Real-time.zip
        print $mx->Dump( stdout => $stdout,
                                   stderr => $stderr,
                                   status => $status );
=cut
}
```

Comment: Can we see the Perl script?

Comment: @JGNI Perl script added (after removing few irrelevant / sensitive parts). Could it be that the output goes to stderr ? Unfortunately not very familiar with Perl...

Comment: You're reading only stdout. Perhaps the script writes to stderr?

Comment: Most likely your Perl script output is mostly going to stderr. You have to find out a way to retrieve stderr from Ganymed, not just stdout.

Comment: warn() in Perl print's to STDERR and your main Java program is only capturing from STDOUT . Change the warn() to print()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of your Perl code that produces the output is:

```
warn Dumper { stdout => $stdout,
              stderr => $stderr,
              status => $status };
```

Looking at [the documentation for `warn()`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/warn) we see:

> Emits a warning, usually by printing it to `STDERR`

But your Java program is reading from `STDOUT`.

```
InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
```

You have a couple of options.

1. Change your Perl code to send the output to `STDOUT` instead of `STDERR`. This could be a simple as changing `warn()` to `print()`.
2. When calling the Perl program in the shell script, [redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT`](https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-shell-script-idiom-redirect/).

   ```
   /u01/app/perl_script.pl 2>&1
   ```

I guess you could also set up your Java program to read from `STDERR` as well. But I'm not a Java programmer, so I wouldn't be able to advise you on the best way to do that.

Comment: many thanks. Eventually I have redirected stderr to stdout  `2>&1` at the level of the parent script call on java code (not on perl script) and it worked fine.